# text in multicolumn doesn't display correctly

Tags: tables

I have some tables created in Latex, but I have some problems with the format. In a multicolumn row, I have some lines of text, but it display the text in a centred format and it overflow at the right of the page.

The code of the table is next:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{UC16. Eliminar taxonomía} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Objetivo} & Eliminar taxonomía y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack{
                    Procedimiento:\\
                    1. Usuario: visita xxxxxxx\\
                    2. Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. \\
                    3. Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio -> taxonomías. \\
                    4. Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado.
                    6. Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos.
                    7. Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
                }   
            }  \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack{Extensiones: -}} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

And this is the result (the grey part is the limit of the page):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would not use `\shortstack`: as you can see, it doesn't guarantee uniform line spacing.

Here's a more complex setup, that on the other hand avoids the table to overflow the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{UC16. Eliminar taxonomía} \\
\hline
\textbf{Objetivo} & Eliminar taxonomía y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
\hline
\textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}{
    @{} r @{ } >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{}
  }
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Procedimiento:} \\
  1. & Usuario: visita xxxxxxx\\
  2. & Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. \\
  3. & Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ taxonomías. \\
  4. & Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado. \\
  6. & Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos. \\
  7. & Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error). \\
  \end{tabularx}%
}   
\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}{
    @{} r @{ } >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{}
  }
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Extensiones: -- }
  \end{tabularx}%
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the big cells I use `tabularx` with a width that makes the table as wide as the text block.

[image]

A different implementation without vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{\textwidth} @{} }
\toprule
UC16. Eliminar taxonomía \\
\midrule
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\textbf{Objetivo} & Eliminar taxonomía y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
\textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
\end{tabularx} \\
\midrule
Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador \\
\midrule
Procedimiento: \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} r @{ } >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{} }
  1. & Usuario: visita xxxxxxx\\
  2. & Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. \\
  3. & Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ taxonomías. \\
  4. & Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado. \\
  6. & Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos. \\
  7. & Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error). \\
\end{tabularx} \\
\midrule
Extensiones: -- \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You forgot line breaks for items 5 and 6 in `\shortstack` and the optional argument to have the stack left-aligned (I suppose you don't want the items to be centred). I added some vertical padding to the cells with `makecell`.

Unrelated: don't use the `center` environment in tables, as it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use \ centering` instead.

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
        \usepackage{makecell, float}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{table}[H]
        \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
            \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{UC16. Eliminar taxonomía} \\
                \hline
                \textbf{Objetivo} & Eliminar taxonomía y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
                \hline
                \textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack[l]{
                        Procedimiento:\\
                        1. Usuario: visita Sidbrint\\
                        2. Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. \\
                        3. Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio -> taxonomías. \\
                        4. Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado. \\
                        6. Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos.\\
                        7. Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
                    }
                } \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack{Extensiones: -}} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
     \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

If you want all tables to  have the same width, you can load  `tabularx` and use an `X` column type:

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l |X| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{UC16. Eliminar taxonomía} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Objetivo} & Eliminar taxonomía y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack[l]{
 Procedimiento:\\
 1. Usuario: visita Sidbrint\\
 2. Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. \\
 3. Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio -> taxonomías. \\
 4. Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado. \\
 6. Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos.\\
 7. Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
 }
 } \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack{Extensiones: -}} \\
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: I have some tables and with your solution they have different widths

Comment: @albert: You didn't mention you wanted all tables to have the same width. I've updated my answer to take this into account, based on `tabularx`.